# Streaming PDF Opens as text in the browser

Tags: java, pdf, filter, http-headers

I am writing a Filter that streams PDF to the browser.  But it is not prompting to open the PDF.  What I am getting is the content of the PDF displayed in the browser window as below:

```
%PDF-1.4 %âãÏÓ 4 0 obj <>stream xKoÂ0ïû+æØJ±CGo<-¤£ªIIIJEüû:Qi9 V¾xvw>ÍÚ{ê+âp-Á\*&_ÑöÄï:'21Ñý- )½¾qÄÔµárÙÌç$¥ÇL÷¢wÝµ·´Ô£W×©^¨ÐØæT&Bg$ L¨wmUÀ2á89ºÓÝ8ª¬Ø Å«C®Ó$O0ØEYQYå÷jÛä¿ó,Æ[ïéµDLÊ´@guj`íÃ .:ÜîOòky#Ü/ªMõÃ_å2Ù:tk¾ôýBµð}eÀÀ,X¨ñ P¾¡ú±zËÁãSo6ÄÔWà?²ë1!Zôs|fÉÉ@QÖ8WzÁ:±.?Îßæçô¾RuÛ endstream endobj 1 0 obj<>>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.28 841.88]>> endobj 3 0 obj<> endobj 2 0 obj<> endobj 5 0 obj<> endobj 6 0 obj<> endobj 7 0 obj<> endobj xref 0 8 0000000000 65535 f
```

I examined the response headers and they show as below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.pdf
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/pdf;charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2011 01:56:17 GMT

3db
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
3 0 obj <</Length 145/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
xœMŽ1Â0…÷÷+ž›.ñ’&M\E‡B ƒ¸U+%µ´‹ßT¨È-÷½û8Þˆ}„0X­B`lpˆ¨0B”Þñ
Ãs¾wÐÂ®7aƒ¢d7û=œÛ)N¥›1«ëÏz¢Æ+¿gjç
Û£¦±Œèoªi
½÷Ê:ÆëÓ=¥õ0¥fµ‰ÝR³ÂÁ¾(V
endstream
endobj
1 0 obj<</Parent 4 0 R/Contents 3 0 R/Type/Page/Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]/Font<</F1 2 0 R>>>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.28 841.88]>>
endobj
2 0 obj<</BaseFont/Times-Bold/Type/Font/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Subtype/Type1>>
endobj
4 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[1 0 R]>>
endobj
5 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 4 0 R>>
endobj
6 0 obj<</Producer(iText 2.0.8 \(by lowagie.com\))/ModDate(D:20111013145617+13'00')/CreationDate(D:20111013145617+13'00')>>
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000227 00000 n 
0000000389 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000477 00000 n 
0000000527 00000 n 
0000000571 00000 n 
trailer
<</Root 5 0 R/ID [<f6f88fa439f0fb7ffd89bb5bcc013692><d7556c8d673d80e2889958cdface8dba>]/Info 6 0 R/Size 7>>
startxref
702
%%EOF

0
```

I have tried:

- Setting the Content-disposition to attachment
- Without Content-disposition
- Setting the MIME to application/download
- Setting The Cache-Control to maxage=1
- Setting the Pragma to public
- I have also set the MIME type in the Tomcat web.xml
- Created a new standard web-app and used the exact same code and it the PDF was generated without a hitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the things that you should make sure is in your Servlet before writing response to outputstream :

```
res.setContentType( "application/pdf" );
res.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                  "attachment; filename=" +
                  "Example.pdf" );
```

attachment tag is used to tell that do not open document in browser but with some PDF Reader application (like Adobe Acrobat)

filename is default name of the file to be used.

Comment: The content-type & content-disposition headers seems to be setup correctly. I can examine the headers in HTTP Analyzer

Comment: which browser are you trying with ? Could you please try using Mozilla Firefox or Opera

Comment: This happens in IE, Firefox & Chrome

Comment: That's weird :( Could you please check if it happens with all the file type ? What if you send a dummy .vcf file and set content type as text/x-vcard. I think what we are trying to do is correct and its browser which is misbehaving :(

Comment: I think it maybe one of the other 6 Filters on the application doing something funny. The reason I say that is because I created a simple web-app and ported my filter in to it without any changes and it all worked fine.  Yet the response headers and content from both web-apps are identical except for the date of-course.

Comment: This answer is not complete. I have the same header and content type set to the response and it still behaves in this way. Strangely, it does this only over HTTPS and not on localhost. Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this problem raise when generate a report with jasperreports.
I find a solution setting this:

```
response.setContentType( "application/pdf" );
```

before setting this:

```
JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream, new HashMap(), cn);
```

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to add a dummy argument to the URL that ends with .pdf.

Comment: Sorry I am not following.  What does that mean?

Comment: Example:
http://www.yourcompany.com/reports/gen.aspx?id=4398&dummy=doc.pdf
id is the real argument, dummy is ...
Browsers will take the .pdf into account to decide to open the PDF reader plug-in.